# If disk space is less than twice of the file size then stop PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I would like to write a script, where I check the disk space, check a file size (which I want to copy), and if the size of that file is at least twice as big as the free space, stop the script.

```
## How much free space
$VarSpace = $(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk | Where-Object -Property Name -eq C:).FreeSpace/1GB

## Exact file
$file = 'C:\Test\Folder1\TESZT.txt'
Write-Host((Get-Item $file).length/1GB)

if ($VarSpace ?????){break}
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Test\Folder1" -Destination "C:\Test\Folder2" -Recurse
```

Comment: You'd also need to deal with the error of actually running out of disk space still. This doesn't prevent it happening.

Comment: Why do you calculate a particular file size and then copy whole folder? Maybe you need folder size `(Get-ChildItem -path C:\Test\Folder1\ -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum ).sum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not convert space to GB - left it in bytes:

```
Clear-Host
## How much free space
$VarSpace = $(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk | Where-Object -Property Name -eq C:).FreeSpace

## Exact file
$file = 'C:\Test\Folder1\TESZT.txt'
$fileSpace = (Get-Item $file).Length

if($VarSpace -gt $fileSpace*2) {
    Write-Output "Enough space"
    Copy-Item -Path "C:\Test\Folder1" -Destination "C:\Test\Folder2" -Recurse
} else {
    Write-Output "Not enough space!"
    exit
}
```